# Sum from one column of dataframe A, based on condition in dataframe B

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

I have the following dataframe (`em`) (excerpt):

```
Year  emissions  Poll    Country  Sector 
1993  0.00000    CO2     Austria  6 
2006  0.00000    CO2     Austria  6.3  
2015  0.00000    CO2     Austria  6   
1998  12.07760   CO2     Austria  5.1  
1992  11.12720   CO2     Austria  5  
1995  11.11040   CO2     Austria  5  
2006  10.26000   CO2     Austria  5 
1998  0.00000    CO2     Austria  6.4.a
```

Then I have another dataframe (`UN_ETScat`). This dataframe contains certain, but not all, `sector` factors which are also contained in the `em` dataframe. I would like to get the `sum` of column `emissions` in dataframe `em` given that the `sector` (labeled `UN_Cat` in second dataframe) is contained in `UN_ETScat`.

```
       UN_Cat             Represented_in_ETS_Cat
1     1.A.1.a                     20
2     1.A.1.b                     20
3     1.A.2.a                     20
4     1.A.2.b                     20
5     1.A.2.c                     20
6     1.A.2.d                     20
7     1.A.2.e                     20
8     1.A.2.f                     20
9     1.A.2.g                     20
10    1.A.3.e                     20
11    1.A.4.a                     20
12    1.A.4.c                     20
13        1.B                     20
14    1.A.1.b                     21
15    1.A.1.c                     21
16    1.A.2.c                     21
17    1.B.2.c                     21
```

For this purpose I have created variable `x` which represents column `UN_Cat` from the dataframe above.

as a layperson, I decided to code like this:

```
sum(em$emissions[UN_ETScat$x])
```

However, I only get `[1] 0` which is not true. What did I do wrong? Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Nordsee

Comment: @zx8754 These are two seperate dataframes. The output is a large number

Comment: @bobbel Thank you for this and it does sound good, but the result is [1] 0

Comment: Could you provide small example input 2 dataframes where they share sector code? From your example input dataframes, of course the sum will give zero, as there is no overlap of sector IDs.

Comment: "I have created variable x"... Also, add how and why you created `x`?

Comment: @zx8754 I have tried the same code as provided by some of you here and have replaced `x` with the title of the column `x` is representing. it is working now. I have just read you post, and yes, `x` was not necessary and caused for whatever reason the issue.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get your question right:

```
sum(em$emissions[ em$sector %in% unique(UN_ETScat$UN_Cat) ])
```

might solve your problem.

Comment: @zx8754, thanks for this, but also here the result is zero.